# How to solve N + 1 issue in select box?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app I have `people` which can have many `projects` and vice versa. The two tables are linked by a join table `jobs`.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :people, :through => :jobs

  def self.names_as_options
    order(:name).map{ |p| [ p.name, p.id, :'data-people_count' => p.people.count ] }
  end

end
```

In one of my forms I have this select box:

```
<%= f.select :project_id, Project.names_as_options %>
```

The problem is that the `count` on `people` gives me an **N + 1** query for each project.

What is the best way to overcome this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try use scope whit lambda, is for that, here is one example how this works:

```
  scope :top, lambda { order('views DESC').limit(20) }
```

in controller just call

```
Project.top
```

this is the best way to filter results in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how exactly would you apply this to my particular use case above? I haven't managed to get it working thus far.

Answer (score 1):

If you use counts, you might better use also counter caches, they are automatically used when needed. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

You could add a "counter cache" of the people count for each project. Ordinarily you would add a field to the projects table via a migration

```
add_column :projects, :people_count, :integer, :default => 0
```

and then declare to use :counter_cache in the Person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :projects, :counter_cache => true
end
```

This probably won't do what you want as it stands, as you are going through a Job join. So, the Person#projects declaration is just a convenient finder, and not used in any callback. But, you get the idea.

You could add a column as suggested above, and then make use of some callback methods in the Job class.

```
class Job
  def update_project_counter
    project.update_people_counter
  end
  after_create :update_project_counter
  after_destroy :update_project_counter
end

class Project
  def update_people_counter
    self.update_attribute :people_count, people.count
  end
end
```

Or something similar thats appropriate. You should then only need the one query.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.names_as_options
    order(:name).map do |p|
      [p.name, p.id, :'data-people_count' => p.people_count]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I already looked into this but I don't like the idea of adding an extra column to my table just for keeping count of the `people`. Isn't there a better way to solve this? I will resort to `counter_cache` columns in a few days though, if I haven't found a better solution till then.

Answer (score 1):

Eager loading will solve this issue, use 'includes' as follows.

Example,

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, -> { includes :customer }
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks. Eager loading would be my preferred way of dealing with this. However, I still don't know where to put the `includes(:people)` in my particular case. I have a many to many relationship, so it's a bit different to your example.